# Sony a6400 Slog2 and minimum shutter speed?

Tags: framerate, sony, shutter

I'm starting with my sony a6400 to get into videomaking (or at least trying to).

I'm shooting a short movie in Slog2 30fps 1080p, but I noticed that I can't set my shutterspeed to be the double of my framerate( 1/60 ), because the camera doesn't allow me to go that lower on shutter speed. How do you manage that? Thanks.